# json dictionary having a variety of the same word

Tags: javascript, html, json

have some html pages and a glossary.json which has glossary terms that are highlighted throughtout the pages and when clicked gives the defintion so for instance

i have a word like:

```
   {
       "term":"Gamer",
       "type":"0",
       "definition":"timekeeping device"
   }
```

and it works fine,
except for when variations of the word appear like "gamers" which appears as(gamer (highlighted then space and S) and gamer's which appears as (gamer highlighted with space and R)

is there a way to make it so that the whole word is highlighted (gamers and gamer's)?

Using a jQuery plugin (zGlossary)
 pretty much a bunch of terms like that in a .json file and a basic page with text inside a

and $('body').glossary('L1P14.Glossary.json', { ignorecase: true, showonce: true

Comment: Maybe you can update the logic so that the matching occurs not only on the word but also checks the word PLUS its plural(s), possessive(-'s), (-ing) and (-ly) forms. You could make sure that within a word string, you find a certain % starting at the 0 index.

Comment: well that essentially is my question... im trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: Gotcha. It would help to show us what you already have. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: nothing complicated, pretty much a bunch of terms like that in a .json file and a basic page with text inside a <p> and $('body').glossary('L1P14.Glossary.json', {   ignorecase: true, showonce: true

Comment: Ah, you're using a jQuery plugin (zGlossary?). You should update your question with that info so people understand how to help.